# Get human readable device/browser combination from user agent string?

Tags: web, user-agent

With LinkedIn you can see a list of sessions, and sign them out from a distance.

Within that list you can see a human readable way what kind of device / browser combination you used for that session.

[image: LinkedIn example]

The current state of UserAgent strings is quite a mess.

**Question:** Is there *a reliable way* (or library) to extract this information clean and reliable from the user agent string?

*What I'm trying to prevent*

One big hairy ball of spaghetti with 30 `if ( str.contains("yadadaya")` under each other that have to tested and that will most likely break or go out of date really fast.

Looking for something preferably in C# or JavaScript

Comment: Do you have a sample exact string from where to extract what you want ?

Comment: Well, I guess that's the problem, there are about infinite amount of combinations, and there is so much garbage in the user agent string nowadays: http://www.useragentstring.com/pages/All/

Comment: [Browser Capabilities Project](http://browscap.org) - i know its not JS nor C#

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You probably want something like [ua-parser-js](http://faisalman.github.io/ua-parser-js/) or [uap-csharp](https://github.com/ua-parser/uap-csharp).